# How to decide whether a p-subgroup of some sporadic groups is cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that H is a subgroup of some sporadic groups (say convey groups Co1, Co2, etc.) and $|H|=p^k$ for some prime p and integer k>1, how to determine whether H is cyclic?

Comment: When would you ever be in a situation where you would know that $H$ is a $p$-subgroup of a sporadic group but not know whether or not it's cyclic?

Comment: Yes. I know that some sporadic groups (say Co1, Co2, etc.) contain some subgroups H with $|H|=p^k$ for some prime p and integer k>1. If k=1, I think H is cyclic. But I am not assure whether H is cyclic or not when k>1.

Comment: All finite groups contain such subgroups of all possible such orders. You will probably need to be way more specific to get a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a more specific version of aPaulT's answer.

There is a minimum value of $k$ for $H$ to be non-cyclic: 2. There is a maximum value of $k$ for $H$ to be cyclic, the p-adic valuation $e$ of the exponent of the group. If $2 \leq k \leq e$, then the situation is ambiguous: there exist both cyclic and noncyclic groups of order $p^k$. If $k<2$ then $H$ is cyclic. If $k>e$, then $H$ is not cyclic.

For most primes $p$ and sporadic groups $G$, $e_p(G) = e$ is at most 1. For the other primes $p$, I list those sporadic groups with $e\geq 2$.

- $p=2$, $e=3$: M11, M12, M22, J2, M23, HS, J3, M24, McL, He, Suz, Co3, HN, Ly, Th
- $p=2$, $e=4$: ${}^2F_4(2)'$, Ru, ON, Co2, Fi22, Fi23, Co1, J4, F3+
- $p=2$, $e=5$: B, M
- $p=3$, $e=2$: J3, McL, Suz, Co3, Co2, Fi22, HN, Ly, Co1
- $p=3$, $e=3$: Th, Fi23, F3+, B, M
- $p=5$, $e=2$: HN, Ly, B, M

In particular, if $p \geq 7$, $k \geq 2$, and $G$ is sporadic simple, then $H$ is not cyclic. This can only occur for p=7 and He, ON, Th, Co1, F3+, B, M; p=11 and J4,M; p=13 and M. Otherwise the Sylow has order dividing $p$, so $k \leq 1$ anyways.

For any prime $p$ and $k=1$, $H$ is cyclic.

For $p=3$ and $k=2$ the situation is ambiguous (sometimes $H$ is cyclic, sometimes $H$ is not cyclic) with J3, McL, Suz Co3, Co2, Fi22, HN, LY, Th, Fi23, Co1, F3+, B, M.

For $p=3$ and $k=3$ the situation is ambiguous for Th, Fi23, F3+, B, M.

For $p=3$ and $k \geq 4$, $H$ is not cyclic.

For $p=5$ and $k=2$, the situation is ambiguous for HN, Ly, B, M.

For $p=5$ and $k \geq 3$, $H$ is not cyclic.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

For a particular sporadic group you know the orders of the elements (eg [here](http://brauer.maths.qmul.ac.uk/Atlas/v3/spor/Co1/#ccls) the conjugacy classes of $Co_1$ are listed, with names of the form $nX$ where $n$ is the order of the elements in that class). If $|H|$ isn't one of the element orders then clearly $H$ isn't cyclic. (Of course if $|H|$ is among the element orders, $H$ may still not be cyclic.) Beyond that you'll need more information than just the order of the subgroup.